# Check for the existence of sub elements within a given HTML element using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xhtml

I'm trying to write a pure javascript function that will take an element from the page (generally a <div>) and from there work out which if it has any *specific* child elements. Which will essentially be any tag that signifies textual content, so: `<p>` or any header tag so (`<h1>` .. `<h6>`) or lists etc.

I'm not looking to manipulate these elements simply check for their existence.

So the function would take the form

```
/**
 * Takes an element and returns whether
 * the element contains content
 * @return boolean (true/false)
 */
var isContent = function (elementToCheck) {

};
```

I'm currently using `document.getElementsByTagName('div')` to get all the `<div>` elements of the page. I will then parse these into the function one at a time.

I've currently got this down

```
var isContent = function (elementToCheck) {
    if (elementToCheck.hasChildNodes()) {
        var children = elementToCheck.childNodes;

        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            // handle children[i]
        }
   }
}
```

I've been trying out using `chilren[i].nodeValue` and testing for equality with various things but I can't get any of them to pass.

What would be the best way to carry on with this? I think it's turning in to a messy function as I'm having to get all the elements outside of this, loop over them and parse them in here which then performs another loop. I'm starting to wonder if it's possible to do it with a regex?

Comment: What exactly do you need to check?  Once you've called `.getElementsByTagName()` you're only going to have elements of the type you asked for.  What is it you need to find beyond just the tag name?

Comment: And no, you can't do it with a regular expression.  The term "parse" in fact is not really appropriate here, because you're working from the DOM, not a raw string representation of a document.  The browser has already parsed that to build the DOM.

Comment: So do you need to check if the node contains some `p` or `div`, etc. tags? Not text contents just nodes?

Comment: So I get all the `div` elements on the page. From here I want to check which of those `div`'s have either a `<p>` or other tag that signifies content as a direct descendent. Maybe this example will help my jumbled explanation: http://jsfiddle.net/EY3Tj/

Comment: You can call `.getElementsByTagName()` from *any* element. So, you can find some `<div>`, and then from its DOM node you can call `getElementsByTagName()` to find all descendant `<p>` tags.

Comment: @nexusmind do you have a list of elements that you need to check for or is that part of your question?

Comment: What about the case of a `<div>` inside another `<div>`?  Should your answer include both, if the inner `<div>` also has a container child?

Comment: @Pointy The only problem I'm considering with that is that I'm looking to check for quite a lot of tags, so I'd have to call `getElementsByTagName()` for say `<p>, <h1>, <h2>, <h3>, <h4>, <h5>, <h6>, <ul>, <ol>` and probably more than that. Which seems inefficient.

Comment: @nexusmind yes that's true; working on a possible answer now.

Comment: @Pointy I've updated the example to clarify what I'm trying to achieve. http://jsfiddle.net/EY3Tj/3/ Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to find all `<div>` elements that have at least one child node that's got a non-empty content model, then something like this work in all browsers back to (and including) IE8:

```
function findDivWithContents() {
  var allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  var di, divs = [];
  for (di = 0; di < allDivs.length; ++di) {
    if (allDivs[di].querySelectorAll('p, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, ... ').length > 0)
      divs.push(allDivs[di]);
  return divs;
}
```

That uses `.querySelectorAll()` to find your container elements.  (You'd have to complete the list of course.)

*edit* alternatively, you could do it backwards: iterate through all the container type elements you're interested in, and check to see if their parent is a `<div>`:

```
function findTheDivs() {
  var containers = document.querySelectorAll('p, span, div, h1, h2, h3, ... ');
  var i, divs = [];
  for (i = 0; i < containers.length; ++i) {
    if (containers[i].parentNode.tagName === 'DIV')
      divs.push(containers[i].parentNode);
  return divs;
}
```

I think this is probably way more efficient. (It might be necessary to add a nonsense "class" marker to each `<div>` to avoid adding it to the list more than once.)

Comment: That's brilliant. Exactly what I was looking for. I'm only just properly learning DOM traversal and whatnot. The `findTheDivs()` way seems much more elegant. Thank you, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a bash at this, though Pointy has mentioned a function new to me called `querySelectorAll()` that might let you cut out the `containsTextElements` loop.

```
var textTags = ["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "p"];

var containsTextElements = function(elementToCheck) {

    for (var i = 0; i < textTags.length; i++) {
        if(elementToCheck.getElementsByTagName(textTags[i]).length > 0)
            return true;    
    }
    return false;
}

var doStuffToDivsWithText = function(callback) {

    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++ ) {
        if(containsTextElements(divs[i]))
            callback(divs[i]); 
    };
}

doStuffToDivsWithText(function(div) {
    console.log(div.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you do not need jQuery, do not need to (but can) specify the tags you want the textual content of and can apply a regex to the found texts.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function logTextContent(elem) {
    var childNodes = elem.childNodes;
    for(var i=0; i<childNodes.length; i++) {
        var nodex = childNodes[i];
        if(nodex.nodeType == 3 /* text node */) {
        var textContent = nodex.nodeValue;
        if(textContent.match(/\S+/) /* apply regex */) {
            console.log("found text: "+textContent);
        }
        }
        else if (nodex.nodeType == 1 /* element node*/) {
        logTextContent(nodex)
        }
    }
    }
    function findDocumentTexts() {
    var docElems = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
    for(var i=0; i<docElems.length; i++) {
        var elem = docElems[i];
        logTextContent(elem);
    }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="findDocumentTexts()">find document texts</button>
<!-- I will fail -->
<div>
    <!-- I will pass -->
    <div>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>
        I should be found straight away
    </p>
    </div>
    <!-- I will fail -->
    <div>
    <!-- I will pass -->
    <div>
        <p>
        I will be missed by the first div but found by the second
        </p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```